# why my value are divided by 2 with bit fields

Tags: c++, endianness, bit-fields

I got some trouble with bitfields and endian stuff...
I confused.

I need to parse some data got from the network, the sent are in lil endian (im using boost::asio)

Can you explain me this

```
struct TEST
{
 unsigned short _last : 1;
 unsigned short _ID : 6;
 unsigned short _LENGH : 9;

};
struct TEST2
{
 unsigned short _LENGH:9 ;
 unsigned short _ID:6 ;
 unsigned short _last:1 ;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 printf("Hello World!\n");

 TEST one;
 one._ID    = 0;
 one._last  = 0;
 one._LENGH = 2; //the value affected here is always divided by 2, it is multiplied by 2 when i cast a short to this structure

 TEST2 two;
 two._ID   =  0;
 two._last  = 0;
 two._LENGH = 2; //the value here is well stored


 bit_print((char*)&one,2);
 bit_print((char*)&two,2);
 return 0;
}
```

[OUTPUT]

00000000 00000001

00000010 00000000

Comment: Is `bit_print()` well tested?

Comment: It's probably irrelevent, but `_ID` and `_LENGTH` are reserved; you shouldn't use names starting with `__` or `_` and an upper-case letter, in case the implementation defines macros with the same names.

Comment: bit_print is used here juste to trying to see what happen in memory. the fact if when i send those structures over the network, i ses that its divided by two.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you saying that the second value is "well stored"? Look at your own output: if the first field (`_LENGTH`) in `two` is supposed to consist of 9 bits, then the second output is also incorrect. It was supposed to be `00000001 00000000`, but instead you got `00000010 00000000`, meaning that in `two` your value got "multiplied" by 2.

I'd guess that your `bit_print` is broken and prints nonsense.

(Obligatory disclaimer: Bit-field layout is implementation defined. You are not guaranteed anything layout-related in C++ language when you work with bit-fields.)

Comment: They are divided by two in both cases.  His bit_print is missing the low bit.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't see it "divided" by two in the second case. If the 9-bit-long field is supposed to occupy the first 9 bits of the second output, then the value we currently see there is 4, while the stored value is 2. I.e. the value got "multipled" by 2 somehow.

Comment: The 2nd byte is 2, not 4 like it should be.